# Greping Load Averages

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-array

I'm trying to grep all load averages & put them in an array. What should be the exact way, keeping in mind the followings requirements.

Defining Array:

```
LA= ("one" "five" "fifteen")
LA= (`(uptime | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+*')`)
```

But the `uptime | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+*'` command gives output like this:

```
3.08
3.49
3.61
```

Requirement: 1. There should be no linebreaks so the averages are separated with spaces and get fit in array syntax.

Values only before the decimals are sent to output or array variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line-feeds aren't a problem when populating an array.  To `bash`, they're just another word separator in this context.

Your command `LA= ((uptime | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+*'))` has two errors:

1. The space after the `=`.  This is valid syntax but does not do what you probably expect it to.

   Instead of assigning the value of the remainder of the line to `$LA`, it sets `$LA` to the empty string and then runs the remainder of the line.

   This is a useful feature for **temporarily** overriding the value of an exported **environment** variable before running a specific command.  As soon as the command exits, the variable's original value is restored.  e.g.

   ```
   $ VISUAL=/usr/bin/joe sensible-editor myfile.txt
   ....
   (exit joe)
   $ echo $VISUAL
   /usr/bin/vi
   ```
2. The missing a `$` before the second `(`.  Without the `$`, your command is not [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), it's shell arithmetic with bogus operands and operators.

Try this instead:

```
$ LA=($(uptime | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'))
$ typeset -p LA
declare -a LA=([0]="0.97" [1]="1.23" [2]="1.39")
```

Comment: Wow, you're a real expert Cas.. than you dude..

Comment: Ok I'm little confused now, why have you assigned array variables a constant value? Whereas I wanted to catch all 3 variables from uptime command..

Comment: i didn't assign constant values. i did exactly what you wanted, capture the load averages from uptime.  the `LA=($(uptime | grep ...))` does that.  The `typeset -p LA` prints the LA array - i.e. it produces the output on the following line.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for misunderstanding..I got confused due to the printed values..

Comment: So I'm trying to echo these variables with tab separators with following
echo "${LA[0]} \t ${LA[1]} \t ${LA[2]}"

But result goes like this...
4 \t 5 \t 4

Can you tell me how to escape the tab character, the right way?

Comment: one easy way is to use `printf`.  e.g. `printf '%s\t' "${LA[@]}" | sed 's/\t$/\n'`.  This prints each element of $LA with a tab after it.  the output is piped into sed to convert the trailing tab at the end of the line into a newline (`\n`) character.  If you want to use `echo`, you'll need to use `echo -e` to enable interpretation of backslash escapes like `\t` for tab (not all `echo` commands support this.  fortunately, bash's built-in echo does).  Run `help echo` for more info.

Comment: damn, i just noticed a small typo error in that command.  The sed command should have a `/` at the end.  should be: `printf '%s\t' "${LA[@]}" | sed 's/\t$/\n/'`

Comment: thanks again... I'm creating a loop for process list, which is given as is

for i in t50P=(`ps -ef | sort -nrk 3,3 | grep -E "httpd -k start" | head -n 50 | awk '{print $2}'`); do
            echo item: $i
        done

But I get the following error, can you help me what am I getting wrong here?
line 46: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 46: `for i in t50P=(`ps -ef | sort -nrk 3,3 | grep -E "httpd -k start" | head -n 50 | awk '{print $2}'`); do'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74343/discussion-between-sollosa-and-cas).